# google tag manager preview button missing

Tags: google-analytics

Why is the preview btn not showing?

[image]

I'm following these instructions:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p2LTMQkf8X0&t=10s&ab_channel=AnalyticsMania-GoogleTagManager%26Analytics

where u can see a preview btn (image from YouTube video)
[image]

Comment: I did not find the btn, the second image is from the YouTube video

Comment: OK, you're right that is strange. Having just logged in, I can see that the video is correct and your tag manager is not showing the preview button where it should. I can also confirm that it offers the preview button even for a container with zero tags. Can I ask, when you set up the container, did you configure it for Web, as opposed to apps or server side?

Comment: Have you tried with a different browser and with no installed browser extensions?  Sometimes adblock or user scripts will remove parts of the page that are actually important.

Comment: I tried with Firefox, same problem

Answer (score 3):

The reason why preview is not there is that you likely don't have the write access to the container. Check your access rights. Preview is not available for certain users.

I know, it seems like little sense to not allow users to obviously just test, but theoretically, by testing bad implementation one can generate bad data in production properties, which sometimes (rarely, really) is a measurable damage to the overall data quality.